# IntelliJ very slow update when using json builder for large object

Tags: java, elasticsearch, intellij-idea

I'm using Elasticsearch's `XContentBuilder` to create a JSON representation of a document type mapping:

```
XContentBuilder mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
mapping.startObject()
    .startObject("someType")
        .startObject("_ttl")
            .field("enabled", true).field("default", "90d")
        .endObject()
        //... and so forth. The full declaration is about 100 lines long.
```

The mapping is moderately sized-- there are about 30 `.startObject()` calls and 60 `.field()` calls in total.

Declaring this `mapping` object causes Intellij to respond very slowly with syntax highlighting/error-checking. If I type `int x = "";` anywhere within the **same file**, it takes about 20 seconds for the IDE to highlight the line as erroneous. If I reduce my `mapping` object to about half the size, it still takes the IDE 4 seconds to respond, compared to the normal sub-second responsiveness. Note that the automatic project make process (I selected "Make project automatically" under IntelliJ settings) performs at the normal speed.

Is this a "bug" of IntelliJ, or are factory methods not meant to be chained so extensively? Breaking up the chain into many smaller calls solves the issue, but is there a better way?

**Additional Info:**

Using IntelliJ 15.0.2 Ultimate edition

Windows 7, 64-bit, 8GB RAM, Core i5-4430 (quad core) @ 3.00GHz

Running 2 VMs and Eclipse IDE on the side and never had a performance problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution other than to break up the statement into smaller ones. It seems keeping the chain length to 5 or less items will give decent IntelliJ reaction times. Example:

```
XContentBuilder mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
mapping = mapping.startObject().startObject("someType");
mapping = mapping.startObject("_ttl").field("enabled", true).field("default", "90d").endObject();
// ...
mapping = mapping.endObject().endObject();
```